# Flash Builder 4.5 + Perforce Eclipse Plugin removes syntax coloring?

Tags: java, eclipse, actionscript-3, flash-builder, perforce

i've installed the Perforce Eclipse plugin successfully in Flash Builder 4.5.

however, the only problem i've run into is that whenever i open a ActionScript file (either one that is or isn't checked out) there is no syntax coloring - it's simply a white background with black text.

i've changed themes so that i have a dark background with different colored syntax but Perforce also removes that coloring, although this time it's the dark background with all white text.

has anyone else experienced this?  any solution?

Comment: i'm using the Perforce Eclipse 3.6 Plugin with Flash Builder 4.5 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues tried that on a Mac and didn't have any issues.  Might be worth an email to Perforce tech support to debug.

Answer (score 0):

First, Can you verify the ActionScript file has right suffix - .as -?

Second, in eclipse Preference > General > Editors > File Associations, make sure you associate the right editor with ActionScript.

This does not seem like a Perforce Eclipse issue.

Comment: they were both correct.  however, Flash Builder 4.5 was acting a little sketchy.  for example, double clicking to highlight a word would often highlight part of the word and part of the next.  i just gave up and i'm using FlashDevelop now.  much more stable than Flash Builder 4.5.  very surprising, though, since it works great on my Mac at home i though it would be more stable on Windows 7 at work.